# Get mapping Workitems when migrating with TFS Integration Plateform

Tags: team-foundation-server

When migrating workitems from a project to another using `TFS Integration Plateform`, is there a way to get the mapping between the workitem id in the old project and the new id in the new project ?

Perhaps in a table of the `'TFS_Integration_Plateform'` database for exemple... but where? I can't find documentation on the database!

If it's in the database, could you give me the table to look for?

My ultimate goal will be to have a plain text file ( a csv for exemple) with for each line having the old and new id. But if I have the table where to look for (or a sql query), I have all I need...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found [what I'm looking for](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/617d2a65-180c-43e3-97fa-b7fe4e6faa8c/tfsintegrationplatform-database-query-to-see-the-old-work-item-id-and-the-new-work-item-id?forum=tfsintegration) :

I should query RUNTIME_MIGRATION_ITEMS table.